# React Native: Fetch API URL in development and productive mode

Tags: javascript, rest, api, react-native

This is how my login function looks like in my react native application. As you can see there is a URL used for API call, which is right now `localhost`. On production there has to be the productive URL of course.

How can I do this programmatically? As I would like to develop on the code without changing the URL all the time...

```
async function login (username, password) {
  try {
    await sleep(2000)
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
      })
    })
    let responseJson = response.json()
    return responseJson
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Could not login')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to inspect the `process.env.NODE_ENV` environmental param and set the URI based on that:

```
const uriBase = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' 
   ? 'http://localhost:4000'
   : 'https://productionURL'

let response = await fetch(`${uriBase}/login`, { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is to use:

```
let url = __DEV__ ? 'http://dev.url.com' : 'https://prod.url.com';
```

from https://facebook.github.io/react/contributing/codebase-overview.html:

You can use `__DEV__` pseudo-global variable in the codebase to guard development-only blocks of code.

It is inlined during the compile step, and turns into process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' checks in the CommonJS builds.

For standalone builds, it becomes true in the unminified build, and gets completely stripped out with the if blocks it guards in the minified build.

For more advanced configuration, I use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

Comment: What is the difference to Rob M. 's answer?